# Excel Lookup Return Unique Value

Tags: excel

I have two sheets one has

```
Item   ID
Box    78
Glue   105
Box    85
```

The other sheet

```
Item    ID
Box
Box
Glue
```

On the second sheet I want to look up the an `ID` from the first sheet.

Where there I duplicates (as in `Box`) I want to return the `ID`s one at a time.
So the lookup on `Box` would return `78` the first time, and `85` the second time.

Like this:

```
Item    ID
Box     78
Box     85
Glue    105
```

Comment: Can you give a very short example which shows what you *want* to happen? It's hard to understand your description.

Comment: Sheet 1
Item  ID
Box   78
Glue  87
Box   105

Sheet 2
Item      ID
Box
Box
Glue

I want a lookup for the ID column in Sheet two that will return 78 the first time it finds Box and 105 the second...and so on.

Comment: Are the ID values unique for all items? or is it only unique within a single item? Like can a Box have id 78 and Glue have id 78?

Comment: They are all unique, no duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution.  Does not require helper columns, does not require array entry.  In Sheet2 cell B2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4=A2)*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4)=0),),0))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  -- The earlier error was mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slight variation of INDEX/MATCH:

```
 =INDEX(B$2:B$4,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$4=C2,ROW(B$2:B$4)-1,""),COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)))
```

Confirm as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, then autofill down.

Explanation of cell references:

A$2:A$4 - Item Column (sheet1)

B$2:B$4 - ID Column (sheet1)

C$2:C2 - Item Column (sheet2)

C2 - The item you're looking up

Comment: Tried this and got #Value!

Comment: Probably a problem with the references. I think you should try tigeravatar's solution, and if that doesn't work for you come back with the exact ranges and sheet names you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this seems impossible, because `VLOOKUP` doesn't know how to deal with multiple `Box`es.

But using [this ingenious answer](https://superuser.com/a/661848) you actually CAN make this work.

On Sheet 1, enter the formulae:

[image: Some formulae for sheet 1]

Which results in:

```
item    instance    combined    id  range_above
Box     1           Box1        78  $A$2:$A$2
Glue    1           Glue1       105 $A$2:$A$3
Box     2           Box2        85  $A$2:$A$4
```

You can now `VLOOKUP` off `combined` instead of off `item`. (Obviously you'll have to do an identical trick in sheet 2.)

Note this all these formulae can just be extended down however long your table is. It will always just work.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I do not have ID's on both sheets.  The ID on sheet two is blank to beginwith...we are populating it via looking up.

Comment: Read my answer again @user290687, and have a little think about it. Once you've converted each `Box` to a `Box1` or `Box2` *on both sheets* you can do the `VLOOKUP` on Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

A good method for doing this would be to use an array formula to look up the values from the first sheet using the number of repetitions of each item from the second sheet. This method requires no "helper" columns.

The formula that will accomplish this is:         `{=INDEX(Sheet1!A:B,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!A:A)=Sheet2!A2,ROW(Sheet1!A:A),""),COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,"="&$A2)),2)}`

This formula is an *array formula*. You can copy it into cell `B2` on `Sheet2`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it. You *must* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula. You can drag this formula down column B for as many rows as you would like.

Your worksheet, when finished, will contain the following formulas:
[image: Finished Worksheet]

Let's break this formula down into its components:

1. Identify how many times a given item has been repeated in column A. We accomplish this with the following code, which will count the number of times that the current row's item has appeared in all previous rows in column A. The absolute reference for the start of the range and the relative reference for the end ensures that the range will be automatically updated as we drag the formula down in column B:

   ```
   COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,"="&$A2)
   ```
2. Identify the *kth* row in Sheet1 containing the item in column A of Sheet2. The following code first uses an `IF` statement to find *all* rows in Sheet1 containing the item in Column A of Sheet2. This uses array syntax to compare all rows in the specified range against a value. The `IF` statement returns an array containing the rows that were identified if any were found. If none were found, it returns the empty string.

   ```
   IF((Sheet1!A:A)=Sheet2!A2,ROW(Sheet1!A:A),"")
   ```
3. Look up the value of the *nth* row that was identified using the `SMALL` function, which selects the *nth* smallest item from an array. For `k`, we pass the count that was calculated in step 1.

   ```
   SMALL(IF((Sheet1!A:A)=Sheet2!A2,ROW(Sheet1!A:A),""),COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,"="&$A2))
   ```
4. Finally, we put it all together in the `INDEX` function, which will look up the value at the specified row (identified in step 3) and column (2), in a given range.

   ```
   {=INDEX(Sheet1!A:B,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!A:A)=Sheet2!A2,ROW(Sheet1!A:A),""),COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,"="&$A2)),2)}
   ```